# spy-training towns

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've heard stories from the Cold War period about towns in the Soviet Union that were imitation American towns where their sleeper agents could be trained to live like an American. I think there was a specific term for these places. Can anyone tell me the word or phrase?

I don't know if the stories are true or not, but that's a discussion for another forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Coca-Cola" City***

What could be more American than Coca-Cola?

> ...KGB bosses are even believed to have built an “American town” in Ukraine so spies could learn how to live secretly in the US.

> In the town, the trainee agents apparently drove American cars using American traffic regulations and watched American movies.

> The Soviets insisted ***“Coca-Cola City”***, as it became known, never existed but those that attended the academy say otherwise.

[New York Post](https://nypost.com/2018/03/09/inside-russias-top-secret-kgb-spy-school/)

> Illegals are trained in their own special classes in KGB headquarters and in their fake country of origin, not in ***"Coca-Cola cities***."

[San Diego Reader](https://www.sandiegoreader.com/news/1998/jul/02/do-any-shadow-towns-soviet-union-still-exist/)

So it is not one of those Russian words  (like *Kompromat*) which was adopted into English spy jargon...just a quintessentially American one.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think that's the term I heard, but it's a very good and useful one.  There may be others. I've upvoted it, but I'll wait a while to see if there are any others.

Comment: Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Replica** or **Mock city** would work.

This article describing training in the USA for military operations in the Middle East uses both terms::

> A Replica of Afghanistan in the Mojave

> ...home to several mock villages built to create realistic training environments for troops due to be deployed overseas.

https://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2013/09/a-replica-of-afghanistan-in-the-mojave/100593/

I presume that in the USSR, they would have had a Russian term for the setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think that's the term I heard.

Comment: @Pete Sorry, I missed where you said you heard a specific term in the past. Are you sure if was not a Russian word transliterated to English?

Comment: I think it was a term used by American intelligence to describe Russian training centres. It's possible that it was a Russian word.

Comment: @Pete I entered “replica american cities in USSR“ in a search engine and got a lot of hits but no term other than super city